# Why is this OCaml definition accepted with a wrong type?

Tags: types, ocaml, type-inference, parametric-polymorphism

I have defined a buggy function:

```
let first : 'a -> 'b -> 'a = fun x y -> y ;;
(* Result: val first : 'a -> 'a -> 'a = <fun> *)
```

The compiler accepts it and changes the type from `'a->'b->'a` to `'a->'a->'a`.
It should not work because the return type should be `'a`, not `'b`.
Correct implementation:

```
let first : 'a -> 'b -> 'a = fun x y -> x ;;
(* Result: val first : 'a -> 'b -> 'a = <fun> *)
```

Why does it work and how to prevent the compiler from changing the type like so? It becomes a problem with more complex expressions.

Comment: OCaml does not have the power to express the type constraint "any `'a` that is not `'b`". Nor does any other language that I'm aware of. If this is more than just a theoretical question, which there's absolutely nothing wrong with, perhaps you could try to explain the problem you're trying to solve at a higher level?

Comment: I want to get exception when I write: `let ex56: 'a->'b->'a = fun x y -> x`. But not rewriting my code.

Comment: That's not possible. And I'm afraid there's not much more to offer at this abstraction level.

Comment: I was thinking that type of function restricts implementation.

Comment: It does, but the only constraint expressed in `'a -> 'b -> 'a` is that the first parameter and return value must have the same type. Both `'a` and `'b` can be substituted with _any_ type, and there's no reason they can't be the _same_ type.

Comment: I finally understood this. The last comment is super useful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, types variables in explicit annotations in OCaml are unification variables. In particular, they can be useful to add some equality constraints. For instance, the `'a` annotation shared by `x` and `y` allows the compiler to detect that in

```ml
let rec eq (x:'a) (y:'a) = match x, y with
| `Leaf _, `Node _ -> false 
| `Node n1,`Node n2 ->
  eq n1#left n2#left && eq n1#right n2#right
```

the case

```ml
| _, `Leaf -> ...
```

is missing but that would not work without refining the type variable `'a` to the quite complicated type of `x`.

The issue is thus that annotation is not the one that you wanted. If you want to enforce that a function has the polymorphic type `'a -> 'b -> 'a`, you can use an explicit universal quantification:

```ml
let wrong: type a b. a -> b -> a = fun x y -> y
```

With this annotation, the typechecking fails with an error:

> Error: This expression has type b but an expression was expected of type a

as expected. Whereas the correct function

```ml
let ok: type a b. a -> b -> a = fun x y -> x
```

compiles without troubles.

Here, the prefix `type a b.` reads "for all possible types `a` and `b`" and this annotation enforces that the type of `f` will be equal to `'a -> 'b -> 'a` without any refinement (aka unification) of the type variables `'a` and `'b`.

Comment: Hah! I did not think of using locally abstract types for this. That's clever! But this won't work for type annotations in general, right? Just for functions definitions? For example, I wouldn't be able to have a higher-order function constrain a first-class function passed to it in this way?

Comment: It should work if you find the right place to introduce the locally abstract types (which is generally problematic for recursive functions). But for instance,

     let map (type a b) = let rec map (f:a->b) =
     function 
     | [] -> [] 
     | x :: l -> f x :: map f l in map 

works as expected

Comment: Right, but if you want to expose this higher-order function and enforce the type inequality on external consumers, you wouldn't be able to express this in a modules signature, I mean.

Comment: Enforcing that the type of a function argument is polymorphic is higher-rank polymorphism. Which requires to use either polymorphic record fields or objects in OCaml, for instance `type id = { id:'a.'a -> 'a} let twice {id} x = id (id, id x)`.

Comment: Right, that too, but you still wouldn't be able to enforce that `'a` and `'b` are different types because that, as I understand, requires locally abstract types as well?

Comment: You could have `{fst: 'a 'b. 'a -> 'b -> 'a}`, but there is distinction between 
* enforcing that the function knows nothing about the relation between a and b, which can be done with either universal quantification, or locally abstract type
* enforcing that two types are not-equal, which is not something that you can ever know in OCaml due to abstraction (even two abstract types could be equal, but the equality could have be hidden by a module interface)

Comment: Ah, yeah I think I get it now. The use of locally abstract types here isn't required, just more convenient I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Using locally abstract types has two advantages here: first, it forces the compiler to emit an error as soon as it tries to unify the abstract type with an incompatible type (rather than when checking the full annotation), second using the GADT-compatible version helps to reduce the number of syntactic variations that people needs to remember.